# Как изменить вид значкам окна Qtdesigner / pyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Как мне поменять вид этим значкам в Qt designer [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я знаю, что можно добавить тему, в которой будут они изменены, но я использую свой стиль.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: а как тему изменить?
типо скачать откуда то?